# Appending instead of overwriting table in BiqQuery API

Tags: google-bigquery

I currently use `bigquery.tabledata().insertAll()` to put data into BigQuery. However it overwrites all previous content instead of appending it. Is there a way to change default behaviour or should I use another method to do so?

Code below:

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(...);

if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
    credential = credential.createScoped(BigqueryScopes.all());
}
bigquery = new Bigquery.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName("Bigquery Samples").build();

TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows r = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows();
r.setInsertId("123");
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Object> props = m.convertValue(person, Map.class);
r.setJson(props);
TableDataInsertAllRequest content =
        new TableDataInsertAllRequest().setRows(Arrays.asList(r));
content.setSkipInvalidRows(true);
content.setIgnoreUnknownValues(true);
TableDataInsertAllResponse execute = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll("", "", "", content).execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to assign [globally] unique ID as an InserID.
BigQuery uses InsertId property to detect duplicate insertion requests on a best-effort basis.
If you will ignore this - you might end up with having unwanted duplicate rows!
See more in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency

Answer (score 0):

Oh, found the answer.
Inserts with same (if set) id by `setInsertId(id)` are overridden by next with same id.

Solution: do not set InsertId.

EDIT: see @Mikhail Berlayant response and why you should care about InsertId.